# Generic XML parser for Poco Objects

Tags: c#, xml

Currently I try to write a generic XML parser and having trouble to write a generic Parser Class.

My current Parser:

```
public class XmlFileLoader
{
        public T GetDeserializedData<T>(Type targetType, string rootElementName, string filename) 
            where T: class
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(GetPath(filename));
            reader.Read();
            doc.Load(reader);
            T result = DatabaseXmlSerializer.DeserializeXmlString<T>(doc.InnerXml, rootElementName, targetType);
            return result;
        }
}
```

My Deserializer:

```
public static class DatabaseXmlSerializer
    {
        public static T DeserializeXmlString<T>(string XmlString, string RootElementName , Type TargetType)
        {
            T tempObject = default;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(XmlString)))
            {
                XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                xRoot.ElementName = RootElementName;
                xRoot.IsNullable = true;

                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(TargetType, xRoot);
                XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

                tempObject = (T)xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }

            return tempObject;
        }
    }
```

My call:

```
var loader= new XmlFileLoader();
var books = loader.GetDeserializedData<List<MySolution.Book>>(typeof(List<MySolution.Book>), "Bookstore", "Books.xml");
```

What is my concern?

I have to pass the type twice, but somehow i can't figure out how to just write it with one type.
I want my call to be  like this:

```
var loader= new XmlFileLoader();
var books = loader.GetDeserializedData<List<MySolution.Book>>("Bookstore", "Books.xml");
```

Comment: You can use `typeof(T)` instead of `TargetType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many errors in your code that I don't know what to do.

It's easier to rewrite the code completely.

```
public class XmlFileLoader
{
    public T GetData<T>(string rootElementName, string filename)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T),
            new XmlRootAttribute(rootElementName));

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filename))
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

This is the whole code!

Use it:

```
var xmlFileLoader = new XmlFileLoader();
var someModel = xmlFileLoader.GetData<SomeModel>("root", "filename");
```

The deserialization code is so simple that you can just throw out this class and just use `XmlSerializer` directly where you need it.

---

However, there is a serious problem when using `XmlRootAttribute`: multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. See documentation: [Dynamically Generated Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0#dynamically-generated-assemblies).

Therefore, it makes sense to cache serializer instances inside our class. Then its presence becomes justified.

```
public class XmlFileLoader
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<(Type, string), XmlSerializer> serializers
        = new Dictionary<(Type, string), XmlSerializer>();

    public T GetData<T>(string rootElementName, string filename)
    {
        var key = (typeof(T), rootElementName);

        if (!serializers.TryGetValue(key, out XmlSerializer xmlSerializer))
        {
            xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T),
                new XmlRootAttribute(rootElementName));

            serializers.Add(key, xmlSerializer);
        }

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filename))
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the Cache issue. I wasn't aware of this details. The whole point of the class to get a simple syntax to quickly setup an integration test environment with an easy syntax.

Comment: Note: For my Usecase I had to use a ConcurrentDictionary  Otherwise i ran into issues while Creating the instances on mutiple threads